# SwiftUI: How can I deselect a button programmatically after the user completes a long press?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a button that can be long pressed for a different action. Here's the problem: if I release after the long press, while still hovering the button, the tap action still fires off. Is there a way I can automatically untap/deselect the button after my long press action runs? Thanks.

```swift
Button("Long Press Test") {
            print("Button Tapped")
        }
        .simultaneousGesture(LongPressGesture().onEnded { _ in
            print("Long Press Successful")
        })
```

Comment: Is it either tap or long press?

Comment: @Yrb Yes it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your tap action just needs to be conditional. The `LongPressGesture` will always fire first as it reacts to the press. `Tap` reacts to the left, so that comes after the press. In `LongPressGesture`, you set a flag that causes the action to skip in `Tap`, and then you reset the flag in tap, after the conditional. An example:

```
struct ButtonTapOrPress: View {
    
    @State var longpPress = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Long Press Test") {
            if !longpPress {
                    print("Button Tapped")
            }
            longpPress = false
                }
                .simultaneousGesture(LongPressGesture().onEnded { _ in
                    print("Long Press Successful")
                    longpPress = true
                })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make the button action block empty. Now you will only get the long press action.

```
Button(action: {})
{
    Text("Long Press Test")
}
.simultaneousGesture(
    LongPressGesture()
        .onEnded { _ in
            print("Long Press Successful")
        }
)
```

Comment: True, but in this case, the button has two purposes (one tap, one long press).